# Getting a Jtoken instead of Doubles in double nested arrays C#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, deserialization

Using Newtonsoft Json in C#, I am having an issue with deserializing some nested data. I am getting a JToken returned instead of the double values that should be in there.
The class roughly looks like this:

```
class Foo
{
public string Identifier;
public List<object[]> Values;
}
```

where the structure of the Values object is as follows:

```
List<object[]>
-> object[] = [double, object[]]
--> object[] = [double[], double[]]
```

now the issue is that the syntax:

```
Foo item = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(jsonstring)
```

returns a correct Foo object, however not all the nested data is deserialized into their .NET object types. The structure that I get returned looks like this:

```
List<object[]>
-> object[] = [double, jtoken]
--> jtoken.children
```

This obviously breaks any code that is trying to address the second layer with default .NET syntax. The application is quite large and preferably the issue is solved in the deserialization step. Please note that the MaxDepth is not changed and therefore deserialization should have an 'infinite' nesting depth... at least to my understanding.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: What does the JSON look like?

Comment: The Json has all the variables correctly stored as arrays.
The problem seems to be solved by, instead of storing arrays inside the object[], make custom objects. This will restore properly which is weird to me but oke